# ¿Cómo guardar registros de un txt a base de datos en python?

Tags: python, base-de-datos

soy nuevo programando en Python. Necesito leer unos archivos e insertarlos en una base de datos. La información que tienen los archivos está separada por "|". Tengo ya separados los registros pero necesito saber como introducir la información a la Base de Datos. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? 
Tengo el siguiente código para separar los registros.

```
f = open('C:\PythonCRUD\prueba1.txt')
for linea in f:
campos=linea.split("\|")
for i in campos:
print (i)
f.close()
```

Comment: Sí, claro que sabemos. Pero, para responderte, tienes que formular correctamente la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, ya sabes: decirnos con qué sistema gestor de bases de datos trabajarás (¿mysql?), qué has intentado, ...

Comment: En internet tienes muchos ejemplos, intenta uno y, si no te sale, modificas la pregunta con el código que has intentado y te ayudamos: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp Recuerda enviarnos el SQL de la tabla que vayas a crear para guarda la información.  ¡Ánimo que es muy sencillo!

Comment: Tal cual te lo han dicho, provee mas detalles como que base de datos usas MySql, SqlServer, etc, la estructura de tu tabla, campos, etc ademas en internet existen demasiados ejemplos de estos , intentalo y donde tengas realmente problemas podrias postearlo editando tu pregunta ...https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247067/edit...

Comment: El problema que tengo realmente no está en hacer una inserción a la base de datos manualmente sino el introducir los datos que tengo en el archivo txt a la base de datos. Intenté guardar los datos del txt en un arreglo pero me aparece error, al parecer por no poner valores default en la inserción, cosa que no quiero hacer pues necesito que los valores que se inserten son los del txt.

Comment: Envíanos unas líneas de ese fichero prueba1.txt a ver qué pinta tiene...

Comment: El archivo tiene este tipo de datos. Tengo que separarlos y después cargarlos a una base de datos.                                                                             1781079|0|536|0|14|765|2019-03-19 10:02:44|2019-03-19 16:02:44|2019-03-19 10:15:29|2019-03-19 16:15:29|215|0|0|0|3||||104|55|104|55|-1|-1|4|2|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|2|4|1|1|1|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|10000062041553011364||004V04014|||10300|||5552787600|2|||||||||||||||||0|2|1|0|0|0|0|
1781080|0|0|493|0|790|2019-03-19 10:02:28|2019-03-19 16:02:28|2019-03

Comment: No es necesario que respondas en los comentarios, modifica directamente la pregunta con lo que te vayamos pidiendo. ¿Qué estructura tienen esos datos? Igual me encuentro nulos, que fechas, que enteros... ¿Qué representan? ¿Cuál sería la semántica para poder modelar la base de datos?